# How to perform dynamic update through MERGE statement in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am performing update from JSON data using MERGE statement. The data contains primary key and the column that was updated from the source system. Since the data contains just the updated column along with primary key, update performed through MERGE is automatically updating other column too to null value. Is there any way through which we could build the update statement dynamically for every row and execute it through MERGE?

```
create or replace table source_data as 

select  parse_json(COLUMN1)::variant   datacol

from values 

 ('{

 "metadata":{"OperationName":"UPDATE"},

 "data":{"id":"1234","status":"Active"}

 }'),

 ('{

 "metadata":{"OperationName":"UPDATE"},

 "data":{"id":"1235","name":"Johny"}

 }');

 

create or replace table employee_destination as

select  column1::text as id,

     column2::text as name,

     column3::text as status

from values 

 ('1234','John','Inactive'),

 ('1235','Jack','Active');

 

MERGE into employee_destination as Target using (select datacol:data:id as id,datacol:data:status as status,datacol:data:name name,datacol:metadata:OperationName as operation_name from SOURCE_DATA) 

AS Source

ON Target.id = Source.id

when matched AND Source.operation_name = 'UPDATE'

THEN

update set Target.id = Source.id, Target.name = Source.name, Target.status = Source.status;
```

Current output:

1234 null Active

1235 Johny null

Expected output:

1234 John Active

1235 Johny Inactive

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
AS Source

ON Target.id = Source.id

when matched AND Source.operation_name = 'UPDATE'

THEN

update set 
--Target.id = Source.id, Why update your PK_ID
Target.name = COALESCE(Source.name,Target.name),
Target.status = COALESCE(Source.status,Target.status);
```